# I installed the Dev Containers extension in vscode, but I don't get the bottom left icon to use it, why?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I install the extension, but don't get the next icon in bottom left, why?

[image]

I will use the extension to connect to docker containers and work on my projects.

Try it re install, but it didn't work.